# How to make a connection with SharePoint's simpleformwebpart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, visual-studio

I am using SharePoint 2010. I primarily work out of SharePoint 2010 Designer, and have some experience with visual studio 2010.

I currently have a log-in page that my "Form" members go to, to log in....

```
http://mysite/_layouts/mylogindirectory/mylogin.aspx
```

When a user goes here, they can simply put in their username and password and click on submit to log-in to the web site. That part works great!

**What I have done so far**:
Inside of SharePoint Designer, within a master template, I imported and branded a form web part onto this master template. I'm using sharepoint's **simpleformwebpart**.

**What I want to do**:
How can I send the form values of my simpleformwebpart to a URL location, after the user clicks the submit button. Is there a specific property tag that I need, in order to make a submit connection?

Is this possible? If so what are some options I have?

Thanks for any feedback!